# Java HTTP AUTH?

Tags: java, http, networking, authentication

I'm trying to connect a desktop application I am writing with the del.icio.us api @ [Delicious API](http://delicious.com/help/api) and simply provide them with my username and password and to request an url to post a bookmark to my profile.

The problem I have is that I don't understand how to send my login credentials when I open a connection.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you mean HTTP Basic Authentication?

Comment: if you look at the link for the api, the example link i would have to type into my browser to add a bookmark is https://api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/add&url=http://www.google.com&description=awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the site you referenced:

> All /v1 api's require https requests and HTTP-Auth.

`HTTP-Auth` is header used in basic authentication.
In Java, you can simply put your credentials in the URL:

```
http://user:pass@www.example.com/
```

You can verify that it was set correctly using the `URL.getUserInfo()` method.

Answer (score 0):

HttpUrlConnection allows you to perform [basic authentication](http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/java-tip-basic-authentication-with-httpurlconnection/). The more powerful HttpClient libraru offers you [more solutions](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html) (basic, digest, and NTLM - which I don't think you need).

Answer (score 0):

If you just need HTTP Basic Authentication, you can form your URL like this:

```
http://user:password@www.website.com
```

---

UPDATE:

Using the example provided, this should work:

```
https://user:password@api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/add&url=http://www.google.com&description=awesome
```

Comment: apparently this doesn't work anymore.. at least not with the account I made. I think it has something to do with yahoo recently taking over delicious

Answer (score 0):

HttpURLConnection does allow you to do basic auth, but if you want more complex authentication to be able to work, give [Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) a shot.  It can seamlessly-handle http authentication schemes like Basic and Digest without you even noticing.

[HTTPClient Authentication Guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html)

Answer (score 0):

This Answer is ok:

```
public String reloadTomcatWebApplication(String user, String pwd, String urlWithParameters, boolean returnResponse){        
    URL url = null;
    try {

        url = new URL(urlWithParameters);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("MalformedUrlException: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "-1";
    }

    URLConnection uc = null;
    try {
        uc = url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        return "-12";
    }


    String userpass = user + ":" + pwd;
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());

    uc.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);

    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = uc.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "-13";
    }
    if(returnResponse){
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    String line = null;
    try {
        line = buffReader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "-1";
    }

    while (line != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\n');
        try {
            line = buffReader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(" IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "-14";
        }
    }

    try {
        buffReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "-15";
    }       
    System.out.println("Response: " + response.toString());
    return response.toString();

    }               
    return "0";
}
```